# Can't execute ffprobe command

Tags: go, cmd, ffprobe

I try to get video file duration with ffprobe. When I run this code I get error:

> exit status 1:

```
var out bytes.Buffer
var stderr bytes.Buffer

cmdArgs := []string{"-i", "bunny.mp4", "-show_entries", "format=duration", "-v", "quiet", "-of", `csv="p=0"`}

cmd := exec.Command("ffprobe", cmdArguments...)
cmd.Stdout = &out
cmd.Stderr = &stderr
if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprint(err) + ": " + stderr.String())
}
fmt.Printf("command output: %q\n", out.String())
```

But when I pass argruments without `-of csv="p=0"` like this:

```
cmdArgs := []string{"-i", "bunny.mp4", "-show_entries", "format=duration", "-v", "quiet"}
```

It works and returns the result (but in bad format):

> command output: "[FORMAT]\nduration=3.008000\n[/FORMAT]\n"

**So what is the problem and how to solve it ?**

Comment: You're only looking at `stderr` when there's an error and only at `stdout` when there's not. You should examine both.

Comment: @Adrian I deleted `stderr` at all and It is still working the same way

Comment: That's the exact opposite of what I suggested.

Comment: There is no need for quotes in `csv="p=0"`.

Comment: @Volker do you meen backticks or quotes?

Comment: @Adrian sorry, but I still don't understand your advice

Comment: Again: There is no need for quotes in `csv="p=0"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try formatting the argument like this (use double quotes for the string instead of backticks and remove the inner double quotes):

```
cmdArgs := []string{..., "csv=p=0"}
```

The Go `exec` package does not invoke the sytem shell to process the arguments, so you do not need to take the same precautions when specifying them. In this case, there's no need to wrap the portion after the first "=" in quotes.

From [the package documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#pkg-overview):

> Unlike the "system" library call from C and other languages, the
>   os/exec package intentionally does not invoke the system shell and
>   does not expand any glob patterns or handle other expansions,
>   pipelines, or redirections typically done by shells. The package
>   behaves more like C's "exec" family of functions. To expand glob
>   patterns, either call the shell directly, taking care to escape any
>   dangerous input, or use the path/filepath package's Glob function. To
>   expand environment variables, use package os's ExpandEnv.

Comment: Thank you for your help!